# Network boot Raspberry Pi 3 using a USB to ethernet adapter

Tags: pi-3, dhcp, u-boot, network-boot

I have extracted the bootcode.bin, .dat and .elf files from Raspbian and put on a SDCard. I have also compiled u-boot and put u-boot.bin on the SDcard. Now when I power on, u-boot loads fine from the SDCard.

I am OK with SDCard with permanently plugged since I am not going to change the firmware or uboot. From this uboot, I am trying to load the kernel over network.

Now when I use the default ethernet port on Pi, I am able to load the kernel over the network.

But for some reason I cannot use the default port and I have to use a USB to ethernet adapter ([model](https://www.amazon.in/Cadyce-CA-U2E-Ethernet-Adapter-White/dp/B00STB1RV8)) . When I do dhcp here, I get the following error :

```
U-Boot> dhcp
Waiting for Ethernet connection... unable to connect.
U-Boot>
```

I assume Pi is still trying to connect over the default port. How can I tell it to use the USB-ethernet adapter? Or is it not possible?

Comment: From this page https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/net.md , "Network booting works only for the wired adapter built into the above models of Raspberry Pi. Booting over wireless LAN is not supported, nor is booting from any other wired network device." . Perhaps this is not supported and hence not possible?

Comment: I don't have any experience but it's clear. You found the answer.

Comment: ***only** for the wired adapter built into the above models of Raspberry Pi* - that's pretty much an equivocal "you can't use a USB ethernet adaptor" so there's no *Perhaps* about it - it is not supported

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks. I always like to double-check and I got my confirmation. Hope this post will help someone else, since I got this page after a day of searching. Stackexchange's indexing is a lot better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [Raspberry Pi documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/net.md) mentioned:

> Network booting works only for **the wired adapter built into the
>   above models of Raspberry Pi**. Booting over **wireless LAN is not
>   supported**, nor is booting from **any other wired network device**.

So, there's no doubt here. It isn't supported